# Different Number of Features in Train and Test Sets - Random Forest sklearn Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using the sklearn package in Python to fit a Random Forest Regression model to data that looks like this:

```
data_train = ['.3 0:.5 1:.2 3:.7 6:.9 7:.1','.2 1:.5 2:.7 4:-0.3 5:1 6:0.7','.1 0:.3 1:.3 2:.2 3:.1 4:-0.2 5:0.3 6:0.7','.5 0:.3 1:.3 2:.5 3:.6 4:-0.1 5:0.4 6:0.6','.4 1:.3 2:.2 3:.2 4:-0.6 5:0.7 6:0.8','.6 0:.8 1:.3 2:.4 3:.4 4:-0.2 5:0.3 6:0.10','.9 0:.3 1:.3 2:.2 3:-.4 4:-0.2 5:-0.3','.9 0:.3 1:.1 2:.1 3:-.4 4:-0.1 5:-0.3','.1 0:.3 1:.3 2:.2 3:-.5 4:-0.2 5:-0.5']
data_test = ['.2 0:.4 1:.65 3:.8 6:.1','.2 1:.3 2:.6 4:-0.2 5:.6 6:0.6','.5 0:.3 1:.3 2:.2 3:.1 4:-0.2 5:0.3 6:0.7','.5 0:.3 1:.3 2:.5 3:.6 4:-0.1 5:0.4 6:0.6','.4 1:.3 2:.2 3:.2 4:-0.6 5:0.7 6:0.8','.6 0:.8 1:.3 2:.4 3:.4 4:-0.2 5:0.3 6:0.10','.9 0:.3 1:.3 2:.2 3:-.4 4:-0.2 5:-0.3','.9 0:.3 1:.1 2:.1 3:-.4 4:-0.1 5:-0.3','.1 0:.3 1:.3 2:.2 3:-.5 4:-0.2 5:-0.5']
```

For each row, the first variable is the output variable, and the others are the feature:value pair.

I create sparse matrices for the data using the following code:

```
def sparse_mat(data):
    row1 = []
    col1 = []
    data1 = []
    y = []
    for rownum,x in enumerate(data):
        x = x.strip()
        elems = x.split(' ')
        for e,elem in enumerate(elems):
            if e == 0:
                y.append(float(elem.strip()))
            else:
                colnum = int(elem.split(':')[0])
                value = float(elem.split(':')[1])
                row1.append(rownum)
                col1.append(colnum)
                data1.append(value)
    X = csc_matrix((data1, (row1, col1)))
    return X,y

X_train,y_train = sparse_mat(data_train)
X_test,y_test = sparse_mat(data_test)
```

I then fit a Random forest regression model using the following code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix,csr_matrix
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50,max_features='sqrt')
rf=rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

However, I then try to use the model from the training set to obtain predictions for the output variable of the test set using the following code:

```
predictions=rf.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 8 and input n_features is 7
```

I understand that the number of features on the training set are supposed to match up to the number of features on the test set. However, in the real world, when I train a model to predict an outcome variable, I may not know what features are available in an out-of-sample testing set.  Is there a way to train  a random forest model with N features and then provide a test set with N-k features and still obtain a prediction?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same problem at my job last week. The way we handled that issue was to create the extra feature in the test dataset and fill it with the imputed values from the training data.

When you start getting into the realm of dummifying class variables however, you can also run into the issue. Again, the approach we used was to group up the values with low cardinalities into a bucket together. If you're pulling data from a database, you'll want to implement this solution is SQL since you want to minimize as much of the data processing in Python, so get ready to use `CASE WHEN` statements.

There's no "correct" answer to this problem. It will all depend on the context of your problem and your data, but I'm just offering certain methods that I used for the same problem that you described.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of creating a dummy observation in my test set with all of the missing features.  Such a pain. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also want to add that there is another method known as the [hashing trick](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-explain-feature-hashing-in-an-easily-understandable-way). It's commonly adopted in NLP because you could have language models that could come across a word that wasn't in the training corpus. Tensorflow has a good explanation and example of feature hashing [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide). Scroll down to the part about feature engineering. Sklearn also has a module for doing feature hashing.